# How repeat last comand (in minibuffer)?

Tags: emacs

Emacs 25.1, Windows 7 64 bit.

Suppose I have some text

```
111111111
222222222
333333333
444444444
555555555
111111111
222222222
```

And I want to find the occurrences of the text **111111111**.

For that I use command **occur** (M-x occur) and it work fine. But 5 minutes later I want to repeat this command, so I try calling the command **repeat** (C-x z) but Emacs doesn't repeat it (**occur** with text **111111111**).

So, how I can repeat it?

Comment: `M-x M-p` will show the last typed command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat complex commands that take arguments you have to use not `repeat`, but `repeat-complex-command`. That will prompt you if you'd like to repeat occur.

To call `repeat-complex-command` you can use the keybindings `C-x M-:`.

Comment: +1. It is also bound to `C-x M-ESC`, and hence to `C-x ESC ESC`. (I use the latter, as I find it easy to use.) And you can use a prefix arg or `M-p` or `M-r` to get to earlier complex commands.